# Как разделить картинку на блоки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

Я хочу разделить картинку по блокам, строкам или словам и получить
Экземпляр каждого блока а также размер и положение его относительно оригинальной картинки например

```
 {'name':'block_1.png','url':'\tmp\block_1.png', 'width':100,'height':100,'x':20,'y':10,}
 {'name':'block_2.png','url':'\tmp\block_2.png', 'width':100,'height':50,'x':30,'y':10,}
```

Пример картинок

1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У многие другие картинки в таком же стиле.

Каждый экземляр отдельного блока(строки или буквы) копируется в папку tmp без лишнего фона

блок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

строка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

буква

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какие нибудь модули(нейронные сети) которые могут это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто. Картинка -- матрица. Её нужно просуммировать по горизонтали и по вертикали. Тогда окажется, что максимальные значения буду как раз в местах белых линий. Далее можете выбрать любой пиксель, по котором разделить картинку.

Comment: Фон может быть разным и неоднородным, прозрачным. Как и цвет шрифта. И я сомневаюсь в надежности такого способа.

Comment: dj_moon. Вы вопрос так задали. В таком случае, Вам нужно приводить больший спектр картинок. Иначе это будет ответ пальцем в небо.

Comment: Мне казалось это слегка очевидным. Но ладно я исправил.